# Mock Service Worker warning in Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt3, msw

While playing around with Nuxt3 for the first time, after some time I observed that the console issues a following warining:

[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/mockServiceWorker.js"

I didn't intend to integrate the MSW, didn't touch the config much, nor do I see any files related.

The next.config.ts file looks like this:

```
import {resolve} from "path"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  alias: {
    "@" : resolve(__dirname, "/")
  },
  css: [
    "~/assets/main.scss"
  ],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  }
})
```

From what I see, the warning pops up only when I'm using Chrome. Any thoughts what causes that and how can I fix it?

I don't see the warning when running the app in the incognito mode. It doesn't appear on Safari or Firefox - so those work. Chat GPT suggests checking the routes in the config file, but I don't have anything specified there.